# Installing linux Mint 17.1 on Acer s5 "No root file system defined"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, system-installation

I have booted Linux Mint from USB stick. Everything works fine until I'm trying to install it. So I launch `Install Linux Mint`  choose my language ⇒ set up WiFi connection ⇒ Installation type shows up (already different from online tutorials).

What do I see:[image]

If I click "install now":  `No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu`

if I click "+": [image]

How to solve this issue?

I'm using Acer s5 laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a hard drive with more than 8GB? Any existing partitions (or a MBR/GPT) on it? Does it show up in `sudo parted -l` or `sudo fdisk -l`?

Can you "+ / - / Change" anything on that last screen? Or is there an earlier screen where you can pick a different option like "Install alongside windows / Replace windows / Something else" where you can pick a different option? Similar to this: [image]

Take a look at these related questions, you may need to create/format some ext partitions using `gparted`, or even a new MBR/GPT, or just pick some from the last installer window (the one in your image). Or possibly `sudo apt-get remove dmraid`

- [“No root file system defined” error while installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu)
- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

---

And in case the above are no help whatsoever, the Mint installer runs `ubiquity` (an apparently customized version 2.18.8-1linuxmint8), *"ubiquity is a graphical installer for Ubuntu, written largely in Python, using debian-installer (d-i) as a backend for many of its functions."*

At least on XFCE it does, you can double-check yours by looking at the .desktop file that's probably on your desktop/in the `~/Desktop` folder, or in the `/usr/share/applications` folder (running a

```
find /usr -iname "*install*.desktop" -type f
```

should find `/usr/share/applications/mintInstall.desktop` too) then look at the file for the `Exec=sh -c 'ubiquity gtk_ui'` line to see exactly what it runs.

`ubiquity` has a "--debug" option, so you can run this in a terminal to see more error messages too:

```
ubiquity --debug gtk_ui
```

Here's what the man page says about "--debug"

```
-d, --debug
       Run in debugging mode, sending verbose information to
       /var/log/installer/debug that may be useful to developers.  (The
       /var/log/syslog file is usually required in any case, along with
       /var/log/partman in the case of problems related to partitioning.)
       Note that passwords will be logged in debugging mode!
```